# How to use unsafeDowncast in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently upgrading a forked Framework to Swift 3.

```
public convenience init<Object: AnyObject>(object: Object,
                        keyPath: String,
                        options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [],
                        block: @escaping (_ object: Object, _ change: Change, _ kvo: KVObserver) -> Void) {

    self.init(__object: object, keyPath: keyPath, options: options, block: { (object, change, kvo) in

        block(unsafeDowncast(object),
              Change(rawDict: change), kvo)
    })
}
```

At `block(unsafeDowncast(object)` the compiler gives missing argument `to:`.

According to [Swift Evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md) `unsafeDowncast` got changed to:

[image]

The passed argument `object` is `x:`, but how do I need to define the `to:` value?

This is, what I have come up with:

```
public convenience init<Object: AnyObject>(object: Object,
                        keyPath: String,
                        options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [],
                        block: @escaping (_ object: Object, _ change: Change, _ kvo: KVObserver) -> Void) {

    self.init(__object: object, keyPath: keyPath, options: options, block: { (object, change, kvo) in

        block(unsafeDowncast(object as AnyObject, to: Object.self),
              Change(rawDict: change as [String : AnyObject]?), kvo)
    })
}
```

The idea was, that `to:` expects the `.Type` and the block says, that `object: Object`. That's why `to: Object.self`.

`change as [String : AnyObject]?)` was a compiler suggestion.

The compiler is satisfied. But I'm not sure if my code is correct. I'm not even 100% sure what the `unsafeDowncast` does in the first place. What does `to: T.Type` means in that context and how do I need to define it correctly?

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 unsafeDowncast(x, to: Object.self)
```

*assumes* that `x` is an instance of `Object` and returns `x as Object`.
So it is identical to

```
 x as! Object
```

but without any runtime checks. If `x` is not an instance of `Object`
then the behaviour is undefined and anything can happen, from crashes
to unexpected results.

In Swift 2, the "destination type" was inferred from the context, in Swift 3 you have to provide it as an argument.

In your case, when the notification center calls the closure

```
 { (object, change, kvo) in
   // ...
 }
```

and you forward the call to the

```
 block: (_ object: Object, _ change: Change, _ kvo: KVObserver) -> Void
```

closure given in the init method, you *know* that `object` is an instance
of `Object`, because that is what you passed in to the registration.

But the compiler does not know that. Therefore `object` must be downcasted to `Object`, and that is what

```
unsafeDowncast(object as AnyObject, to: Object.self)
```

does. The additional cast `as AnyObject` is necessary because in 
the notification callback, `object` has type `Any`, and not `AnyObject`
as in Swift 2. So your code

```
block(unsafeDowncast(object as AnyObject, to: Object.self), ...)
```

is correct, but the more straightforward way would be

```
block(object as! Object, ...)
```

The forced cast is acceptable here because you know that it must succeed,
otherwise you would have a *programming error*.

Comment: thank you VERY much for the time, effort and explanation

Comment: Hi Martin, can you confirm that the difference between unsafeDowncast and ' as! ' is that ' as! ' performs a type check and unsafeDowncast does not? Or are there more difference? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1640972-unsafedowncast doesn't really help :(

Comment: @J.Doe: That is how I understand [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1640972-unsafedowncast).